# How to read and write out this kind of bitmap format

Tags: javascript, bitmap

I saw a piece of bitmap code in javascript:

```
MyProj.Resources.createImage("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFoAAABaCAYAAAA4qEECAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAD8hJREFUeNrsXGtsZVUV3uec++jTd.....uQmCC"),
```

here I omitted a large part of the contents. How to write these String-like bitmap into real png? for example in C#

Comment: It is base64 encoded binary, just base64_decode it and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an example of a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) using [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding for its payload.

You can extract that payload and decode it in C# using [FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx), something like this...

```
byte[] binaryData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
```

Answer (score 0):

use base64 to decode the string from **`,`** to the end of the string. and what you get write into a file with the .png extension. That if the mime-type you read after `data:` is image/png. If it's image/gif or jpeg then the extension should be gif or jpeg. To create a string like that from a image, you have to respect that convention `data:mime-type;base64,base64_encoded_string_of_thefile`